# jsdoc socket.io @param

Tags: javascript, ide, socket.io, intellisense, jsdoc

[image: et]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как указать ide, что io это Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный тип `import('socket.io').Server`:

```
/** @param {import('socket.io').Server} io */
module.exports = (io) => {
  io.on()
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]